# Question about creating a package tutorial

Tags: ros, catkin, beginner-tutorials, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently learning how to use ros right now and going through the tutorials and I'm on this one

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage

Everything works fine until I get to step 5.1 when it comes to First Order Dependencies

```
I use catkin_create_pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp
```

However when I try the next command `rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials`, it doesn't work.

Here's is the long from my terminal

```
angelo@angelo-Satellite-S55t-B:~/catkin_ws/src$ catkin_create_pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp
Created file beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt
Created file beginner_tutorials/package.xml
Created folder beginner_tutorials/include/beginner_tutorials
Created folder beginner_tutorials/src
Successfully created files in /home/angelo/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials. Please adjust the values in package.xml.
angelo@angelo-Satellite-S55t-B:~/catkin_ws/src$ rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials
[rospack] Error: no such package beginner_tutorials
```

I should be getting this instead, but I'm not

```
std_msgs
rospy
roscpp
```

I'm currently using ROS Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04. I also realize there is a bug that's reported in the tutorial, but I believe the bug was referring to a segmentation fault.

What should I do next?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200549/question-about-creating-a-package-tutorial/) by [aadkinz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21289/aadkinz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that the tutorials missed a crucial step. Before you are able to *use* your ROS package you need to build the workspace and also source the generated setup file. This will especially add you source folder to the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

I have updated the tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/action/diff/ROS/Tutorials/catkin/CreatingPackage?action=diff&rev1=25&rev2=26

Please try it with the newly added step: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage#ROS.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-catkin.2BAC8-CreatingPackage.Building_a_catkin_workspace_and_sourcing_the_setup_file

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aadkinz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21289/aadkinz/) on 2015-01-07**:
Ok that worked.

Thanks!